# Angular 2 - refresh with query params is breaking my app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular2-routing

I have query params in my url and after success?=params I redirect away from those params so they are cleared from the url but if I press back it goes back to those params and then if I press refresh it does something illegal - it redoes the same transaction that just completed and pushes that change to my database using http.post and the same query params. This pushes the same thing that was already pushed to my databases array and does a $inc operation. This is a huge vulnerability! What is the best way to avoid this vulnerability?

Comment: Why do you think this is related to Angular? You have to ensure yourself that your code doesn't make requests you don't want to be made.

Comment: Yea I agree. I am looking for the best method to avoid this vulnerability server-side. How do I check whether the same http request was made by the same client with the same params already and prevent it from being made again using servers-side logic with expressjs server and an incoming router.post method?

Answer (score 1):

You can never trust anything that comes from the client, especially query string. You need to implement checks on the server to make sure all you transactions are legal.

Comment: Yea I agree. I am looking for the best method to avoid this vulnerability server-side. How do I check whether the same http request was made by the same client with the same params already and prevent it from being made again using servers-side logic with expressjs server and an incoming router.post method?

Comment: You can check if the row already exists in your database, unless you are logging post requests.